# Django SQL LIKE on integer values?

Tags: sql, django

I have a PostgreSQL table with `id` field (`bigint`). Can I somehow (possibly with ORM) perform check that `id` value ends with '`00000`' (e. g. "7500000", "7600000", but not "123456")? 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: what about `.. where id like '%00000'` ?

Comment: LIKE operator is not compatible with numeric types. Actually I need something like 
    SELECT ... WHERE CAST(id as varchar(255)) LIKE '%00000';
but in Django ORM...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django has an [`__endswith` clause](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-endswith) you could use.

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(myfield__endswith='00000') #id in your case
```

This fetches the queryset with all ids that end with `00000`

Now, if you have an objects' instance at hand, and need to check if it ends with `00000`, you dont need the ORM. You can do something like:

```
if str(myObject.id).endswith('00000'):
```

DEMO:

```
>>> str(10000000).endswith('00000')
True
```

Comment: Note that this is terribly (and I mean terribly) inefficient, as the database has to convert all numeric data into strings to do the compare. EVERY. SINGLE. TIME you do that query. It's probably OK for a table with 20 entries, but not for anything of interesting size.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `YourModel.objects.filter(id__endswith='00000')`. It should also works on int fields :)

Answer (score 1):

If you work with numerical types, why don't you use numerical operations?

```
... WHERE id % 100000 = 0
```

should do what you want.